# Map object inside array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is my array:

```
const array = [
    {
        "fare": "399.00",
        "passenger": {
            "age": "21",
            "gender": "MALE",
            "name": "Test1"
        },
    },
    {
        "fare": "399.00",
        "passenger": {
            "age": "21",
            "gender": "FEMALE",
            "name": "Test2"
        },
    }
]
```

How to map the object inside the array, and how to convert the object to the required output

**Required output:**

```
Test1(M), Test2(F)
```

Above contains "name" and gender - if its male then just "M" and if its female just "F"

As of now i tried,

```
array.map(o => ({ name: o.passenger.name, gender: o.passenger.gender })))
```

But how to convert this as expected output !

Comment: How do you know gender of `Test2`? To convert: `o.passenger.name + '(' + (o.passenger.gender.substring(0, 1)) + ')'`

Comment: sorry typo, check now @Justinas

Comment: Why is the required output `Test1(M), Test2(M)` if `Test2` is female?

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```js
const array = [{ "fare": "399.00", "passenger": { "age": "21", "gender": "MALE", "name": "Test1" }, }, { "fare": "399.00", "passenger": { "age": "21", "gender": "FEMALE", "name": "Test2" }, } ];

const output = array
  .map(({passenger}) => `${passenger.name}(${passenger.gender.slice(0,1)})`)
  .join(", ")

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop your array and make new string:

```js
const array = [
        {
            "fare": "399.00",
            "passenger": {
                "age": "21",
                "gender": "MALE",
                "name": "Test1"
            },
        },
        {
            "fare": "399.00",
            "passenger": {
                "age": "21",
                "gender": "FEMALE",
                "name": "Test2"
            },
        }
    ];
    
var states = array.map((o) => o.passenger.name + '(' + o.passenger.gender.substring(0, 1) + ')')

console.log(states);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the expected result you want?

```js
const array = [{
  "fare": "399.00",
  "passenger": {
    "age": "21",
    "gender": "MALE",
    "name": "Test1"
  },
}, {
  "fare": "399.00",
  "passenger": {
    "age": "21",
    "gender": "FEMALE",
    "name": "Test2"
  },
}]

const passengers = array.map(o => {
  const gender = o.passenger.gender == 'MALE' ? 'M' : 'F';
  return o.passenger.name + '(' + gender + ')';
})

console.log(passengers.join(', ')); // Test1(M), Test2(F)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the objects to strings and join them

```js
const array = [{ "fare": "399.00", "passenger": { "age": "21", "gender": "MALE", "name": "Test1" }, }, { "fare": "399.00", "passenger": { "age": "21", "gender": "FEMALE", "name": "Test2" }, } ]

const output = array.map(o => o.passenger.name + (o.passenger.gender === "MALE" ? "(M)" : "(F)")).join(', ')

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and `destructruing`

```js
const tests = (arr) =>
  arr
    .map(
      ({
        passenger: {
          gender: [G],
          name,
        },
      }) => `${name}(${G})`
    )
    .join(", ");

const array = [
  {
    fare: "399.00",
    passenger: {
      age: "21",
      gender: "MALE",
      name: "Test1",
    },
  },
  {
    fare: "399.00",
    passenger: {
      age: "21",
      gender: "FEMALE",
      name: "Test2",
    },
  },
];

console.log(tests(array));
```